# Are Multiple Iterations possible in the Dictionary Comprehension in the Python, like the Lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, dictionary-comprehension

In some special cases, can we use the multiple iterations in the dictionary comprehensions?

For Example, we have a string in the below format:-

```
"6: 14, 11: 28, 17: 74, 22: 7, 38: 59, 49: 12, 57: 76, 61: 54, 81: 98, 88: 4"
```

So If I want to set `6,11,17,22,38,......` as the keys
and `14,28,74,7...` as the corresponding values
How can it be achieved by Dictionary Comprehensions?

Comment: If by "multiple iterations" you mean "multiple nested `for` loops", then yes, you can use them in any comprehension

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert a string to a dictionary:

```
import ast

my_string = "6: 14, 11: 28, 17: 74, 22: 7, 38: 59, 49: 12, 57: 76, 61: 54, 81: 98, 88: 4"
my_dict = ast.literal_eval(f"{{{my_string}}}")
```

Answer (score 0):

there are multiple possibility:

**With Regex:**

```
import re
sample = "6: 14, 11: 28, 17: 74, 22: 7, 38: 59, 49: 12, 57: 76, 61: 54, 81: 98, 88: 4"
my_dict = {key: value for key, value in re.findall('(\d+): (\d+)', sample)}
print(my_dict)
```

output:

```
{'6': '14', '11': '28', '17': '74', '22': '7', '38': '59', '49': '12', '57': '76', '61': '54', '81': '98', '88': '4'}
```

**With Split():**

```
sample = "6: 14, 11: 28, 17: 74, 22: 7, 38: 59, 49: 12, 57: 76, 61: 54, 81: 98, 88: 4"
my_dict = {elem.split(": ")[0]: elem.split(": ")[1] for  elem in sample.split(", ")}
print(my_dict)
```

output:

```
{'6': '14', '11': '28', '17': '74', '22': '7', '38': '59', '49': '12', '57': '76', '61': '54', '81': '98', '88': '4'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `dict` constructor

```
dict(x.replace(' ', '').split(':') for x in s.split(','))
```

Or use `dict` constructor and `map` function

```
dict(map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '').split(':'), s.split(',')))
```

Output

```
{'6': '14', '11': '28', '17': '74', '22': '7', '38': '59', '49': '12', '57': '76', '61': '54', '81': '98', '88': '4'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary comprehension combined with `split()` on `:` should be good enough:

```
dic = {elt.split(':')[0].strip(): elt.split(':')[1].strip() for elt in string.split(',')}
```

Output:

```
{'6': '14', '11': '28', '17': '74', '22': '7', '38': '59', '49': '12', '57': '76', '61': '54', '81': '98', '88': '4'}
```

If you want keys and values to be as `int` objects:

```
dic = {int(elt.split(':')[0].strip()): int(elt.split(':')[1].strip()) for elt in string.split(',')}
```

Output:

```
{6: 14, 11: 28, 17: 74, 22: 7, 38: 59, 49: 12, 57: 76, 61: 54, 81: 98, 88: 4}
```

Answer (score 0):

Required output can be achieved with below comprehension:

```
>>> s1 = "6: 14, 11: 28, 17: 74, 22: 7, 38: 59, 49: 12, 57: 76, 61: 54, 81: 98, 88: 4"
>>> dict((s[0].strip(),int(s[1].strip())) for s in [s.split(":") for s in s1.split(",")])
{'11': 28, '38': 59, '17': 74, '22': 7, '49': 12, '57': 76, '61': 54, '88': 4, '6': 14, '81': 98}
>>>
```